# EJS and connect-flash doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, connect-flash

I'm trying to wrap my brain around templates and flash messages using EJS and connect-flash along with express and express-session, but I can't seem to get it to work the way I want or expected.

When I define a flash message I console.log it, and I can see it just fine. But when I try to print it in my template, `req.flash` is an empty object [object Object].

The flash message in console.log after failed login attempt:

`flash(): { error: [ 'Brugernavn eller adgangskode er ikke korrekt.' ] }`

But when I try to loop through `flash` in my ejs template with something like

```
<% flash.forEach(function (message) { %>
    <p><%=message%></p>
<% }) %>
```

The above returns an error on

```
TypeError: C:\path\to\my\stuff\auth-test\views\login.ejs:7
    [snippet with line indicator, not important]
flash.forEach is not a function
```

**server.js**

```
const myExpress = require('express')
const myApp = myExpress()
const myBodyParser = require('body-parser')
const flash = require('connect-flash')
const mySession = require('express-session')
const myLogger = require('morgan')
const myFs = require('fs')
const myPath = require('path')
const myEjs = require('ejs')
const myLRU = require('lru-cache')
const myAccessLogStream = myFs.createWriteStream(myPath.join(__dirname, 'logs', 'access.log'), { flags: 'a' })
const myPort = process.env.PORT || 1337

const myAuthCheck = function (myRequest) {
    if (!myRequest.session || !myRequest.session.authenticated) {
        return false
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}

myApp.engine('ejs', require('express-ejs-extend'))
myApp.set('view engine', 'ejs')

myEjs.cache = myLRU(100)

myApp.use(flash())
myApp.use(mySession({ secret: 'meget hemmelig streng', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }))

myApp.use(myBodyParser.urlencoded({'extended': 'true', limit: '50mb'}))
myApp.use(myBodyParser.json())
myApp.use(myBodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json', limit: '50mb' }))

myApp.use(myLogger('combined', { stream: myAccessLogStream }))

var hourMs = 1000 * 60 * 60
myApp.use(myExpress.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: hourMs }))

require('./routers/frontendRouter')(myApp, myAuthCheck)

myApp.listen(myPort)

console.log('Serveren kører på http://localhost:' + myPort)
```

**frontendRouter.js**

(pay notice to the .post and .get routes for '/login')

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

module.exports = function (myApp, myAuthCheck) {

    myApp.get('/', function (myRequest, myResponse) {
        myResponse.render('home', { title: 'Hello, World!', data: 'Something wicked this way comes!' })
    })

    myApp.get('/test', function (myRequest, myResponse) {
        myResponse.render('article', { title: 'Dette er en test', data: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor veniam voluptatibus vel omnis nostrum maiores, placeat! Nam ea asperiores, sint, aut reprehenderit eos, facere ipsum in, ratione sunt ab fugiat?'})
    })

    myApp.get('/profile', function (myRequest, myResponse) {
        if (!myAuthCheck(myRequest)) {
            myResponse.render('403', { title: 'Adgang forbudt', status: 403 })
        }
        else {
            myResponse.render('profile', { title: 'Profil' })
        }
    })

    myApp.post('/login', function (myRequest, myResponse) {
        if (myRequest.body.username && myRequest.body.username === 'admin' && myRequest.body.password && myRequest.body.password === '1234') {
            myRequest.session.authenticated = true
            myResponse.redirect('/profile')
        }
        else {
            myRequest.flash('error', 'Brugernavn eller adgangskode er ikke korrekt.')
            console.log('flash():', myRequest.flash())
            myResponse.redirect('/login')
        }
    })

    myApp.get('/login', function (myRequest, myResponse) {
        myResponse.render('login', { title: 'Log ind', flash: myRequest.flash() })
    })

    myApp.get('/logout', function (myRequest, myResponse) {
        delete myRequest.session.authenticated
        myResponse.redirect('/')
    })

}
```

**login.ejs**

```
<% extend('layout') %>
<section>
    <h1><%=title%></h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <p><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Brugernavn"></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Adgangskode"></p>
        <% flash.forEach(function (message) { %>
            <p><%=message%></p>
        <% }) %>
        <button type="submit">Log ind</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

**EDIT:**

I've console.log()'ed req.flash() both on the sending and receiving end now:

```
myApp.get('/login', function (myRequest, myResponse) {
    console.log('flash():', myRequest.flash())
    myResponse.render('login', { title: 'Log ind', flash: myRequest.flash() })
})
```

And the result on the receiving end is

`flash(): {}`

Comment: forEach is array only... Is flash really an array?

Comment: What happens if you try to replace flash.forEach(... with

       <% for(message in messages) { %>
            <p><%=message%></p>
        <% }) %>

Comment: Yeah I've considered this too @jonas w but I also tried treating it as an object and json string. It's still empty, as in { }

Comment: @JackRobson just tried, no output at all. I had to do for(message in flash) {}, since `messages`is not defined...

Comment: I've just realised, I gave up on trying to get connect-flash to work and instead use: 'express-flash-messages'. Try changing your const flash = require('connect-flash') to const flash = require('express-flash-messages'); install the npm module and see if it'll help.

Comment: @JackRobson I just looked it up. Syntax looks the same, so I will give it a quick try. Thank you.

Comment: syntax is a little different getting the flash messages on the page,

I have to run var messages = getMessages() inside the template.

Comment: @JackRobson hmmm, nope... now I'm getting a whole other error. SyntaxError: Unexpected token ... on node_modules/express-flash-messages\index.js:21

Comment: Hm... I'm stumped. Sorry I couldn't help further.

Comment: @JackRobson thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned from `flash()` is an object:

```
{ error: [ 'Brugernavn eller adgangskode er ikke korrekt.' ] }
```

So to handle and show errors, you'd use something like this:

```
<% (flash.error || []).forEach(function(message) { %>
    <p><%=message%></p>
<% }) %>
```

Or a bit more explicitly (by *only* passing error flash messages to the template):

```
// code
res.render('template', { errors : req.flash('error') || [] });

// template
<% errors.forEach(function(message) { %>
  <p><%=message%></p>
<% }) %>
```

To solve the issue of the object being empty in `GET /login`, make sure that you don't call `req.flash()` anywhere in between setting it and getting it (like, for instance, by `console.log`'ing it). Once you call `req.flash()`, all stored messages are deleted (very undocumented, but that's how `req.flash()` behaved in Express 2.x, which `connect-flash` is trying to mimic).

Comment: The object is still empty on the receiving end, this wont work until that issue is resolved. I do see your logic though.

Comment: @BrianEmilius see my edit. In short: don't call `req.flash()` more than once if you want to retrieve stored messages.

Comment: It was console.log that messed it up all along! Thank you for this answer, it saved my day :) It should really be part of the documentation to be honest.

Comment: @BrianEmilius I completely agree! It's very confusing behaviour if you don't know the exact background.